# DDD: Applying Event Store in a legacy system

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, domain-events

Our current system is a legacy system which doesn't use `domain events`. We are going to start publishing `domain events`.
Other bounded contexts are going to listen to these `domain events`, but only from the time we start publishing, losing all the past information.

Then, how to deal with this legacy system which didn't record these events, but somehow we want to have a past history before the implementation of this event store system?

Is it a good approach trying to figure out what happened and try to create the domain events (reverse engineering) according to the data we have in our DB?

Answer (score 8):

I wouldn't go down the route of trying to reverse engineer events for a legacy system, *unless there is a business reason to do so* - is your use case just that you want to fit into the new way you'll be modelling things using events? If there's no business case for it, it sounds like a waste of effort.

How about having a single starting event that represents the current state of each of your 'things' (i.e. Aggregates if you're using DDD concepts) as they exist now in the legacy system? Then add new events on top of this.

I.e.

LegacySystemStateCaptured

NewDomainEvent

AnotherNewDomainEvent

...then when you rebuild your state, apply the LegacySystemStateCaptured event as well as the others.

Comment: Nice answer.  I would also add that depending on the `Snapshot` implementation one could even record the data that would've been in a`LegacySystemStateCaptured` event as a snapshot event since it would probably contain all the typical data anyway.  This will save on the once-off event but it will definitely depend on the implementation.

Comment: Yes totally. Please feel free to edit my answer with this suggestion :)